# Integral of the floor function. Can anyone prove the following identity?

Tags: integration, ceiling-and-floor-functions

How can I show that $$\int_{2}^{x} \lfloor \log_{y} {x} \rfloor ~ dy = x$$

or failing that $$\int_{2}^{x} \lfloor \log_{y} {x} \rfloor ~ dy \sim x$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can certainly not prove the first statement, since it is false for $x=2$ (when the left side of the equation equals $0$).

Comment: Sorry I should say for $x > 2$ or possible even  just showing for sufficiently large $x$ would be strong enough for my purpose.

A few tests on wolfram seem to give that the integral is $=x-2 \sim x$ but how do I show it....

Comment: Graphically it is clear that the first equality is not true. However it seems that the second is true.

Comment: Yes, i released shortly after posting but decided to leave the original question intact. Did you plot this in matlab? May i see the plot, or could you post the code would be incredibly useful.

Comment: @kingpee mathematica says that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1x\int_2^x\lfloor\log_y x\rfloor\mathrm dy=0$$ (I deleted the graph, anyway I did with mathematica.) However $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1x\int_2^x\log_y x\,\mathrm dy=1$$

Answer (score 2):

$$S(x)=\int_{2}^{x} \lfloor {\log_{y} {x} }\rfloor ~ dy = \int_{2}^{x} \big\lfloor \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(y)} \big\rfloor ~ dy $$
Change of variable : $\quad t=\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(y)} \quad\to\quad y=x^{1/t}\quad\to\quad dy=-\frac{x^{1/t}\ln(x)}{t^2}dt$

$$S(x)=\int_{1} ^{\ln(x)/\ln(2)} \lfloor {t}\rfloor \frac{x^{1/t}\ln(x)}{t^2}~ dt $$

$n= \lfloor {\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)}}\rfloor \quad\to\quad \ln(x)\int_{1}^n \lfloor {t}\rfloor \frac{x^{1/t}}{t^2}~ dt <S(x)< \ln(x)\int_{1} ^{n+1} \lfloor {t}\rfloor \frac{x^{1/t}}{t^2}~ dt$

$$\int_{1}^n \lfloor {t}\rfloor \frac{x^{1/t}}{t^2}~ dt = \sum_{k=2}^n \int_{k-1}^k \lfloor {t}\rfloor \frac{x^{1/t}}{t^2}~ dt  = \sum_{k=2}^{n} (k-1) \int_{k-1}^k\frac{x^{1/t}}{t^2}~ dt$$

$$\ln(x)\sum_{k=2}^{n} (k-1) \int_{k-1}^k\frac{x^{1/t}}{t^2}~ dt <S(x)< \sum_{k=2}^{n+1} (k-1) \int_{k-1}^k\frac{x^{1/t}}{t^2}~ dt$$

$\int_{k-1}^k\frac{x^{1/t}}{t^2}~ dt = \left[-\frac{x^{1/t}}{\ln(x)}\right]_{t=k-1}^{t=k} = \frac{x^{1/(k-1)}-x^{1/k} }{\ln(x)}$

$$\sum_{k=2}^{n} (k-1)\left(x^{1/(k-1)}-x^{1/k}\right)  <S(x)< \sum_{k=2}^{n+1} (k-1)\left(x^{1/(k-1)}-x^{1/k}\right)$$

$$\sum_{k=2}^{n} (k-1)\left(x^{1/(k-1)}-x^{1/k}\right)  <S(x)< \sum_{k=2}^{n+1} (k-1)\left(x^{1/(k-1)}-x^{1/k}\right)$$

$$f_n(x)=\frac{1}{x}\sum_{k=2}^{n} (k-1)\left(x^{1/(k-1)}-x^{1/k}\right) $$

$$f_n(x)<\frac{S(x)}{x}<f_{n+1}(x)$$

After simplification :

$$f_n(x)=1+\sum_{k=2}^{n-1} x^{-(k-1)/k}-(n-1) x^{-(n-1)/n}$$

$\frac{1}{2}\leq\frac{k-1}{k}<1 \text{ and } x>1 \quad\to\quad \frac{1}{x}<x^{-(k-1)/k}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$

$\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)}-1 \leq n= \lfloor {\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)}}\rfloor< \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)} $

$\frac{n-2}{x}\leq \sum_{k=2}^{n-1} x^{-(k-1)/k} <\frac{n-2}{\sqrt{x}} <\frac{n-2}{\sqrt{x}} \quad\to\quad \frac{\left( \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)}-1\right) -2}{x}\leq \sum_{k=2}^{n -1} x^{-(k-1)/k} <\frac{\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)} -2}{\sqrt{x}} $

$$x\to\infty \quad\implies\quad \frac{\ln(x)}{x}\to \text{ and }\frac{\ln(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\to 0\quad\implies\quad \sum_{k=2}^{n -1} x^{-(k-1)/k}\to 0$$

$(\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)}-2)x^{(1/\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)})-1}< (n-1)x^{-(n-1)/n} < (\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)}-1) x^{(1/(\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)}-1))-1}$

$2\frac{\ln(x)-2\ln(2)}{\ln(2)x} < (n-1)x^{-(n-1)/n} < \frac{\ln(x)-\ln(2)}{\ln(2)x}x^{1/((\ln(x)/\ln(2))-1)}$

$x\to\infty \quad\implies\quad 1/(\ln(x)/\ln(2)-1)\to 0 \quad\implies\quad \frac{\ln(x)-\ln(2)}{\ln(2)x}x^{1/((\ln(x)/\ln(2))-1)}\to 0$

$$x\to\infty \quad\implies\quad (n-1)x^{-(n-1)/n}\to 0$$

$$x\to\infty \quad\implies\quad f_n(x)=1+\sum_{k=2}^{n-1} x^{-(k-1)/k}-(n-1) x^{-(n-1)/n}\to 1$$

$$f_n(x)\leq \frac{S(x)}{x}<f_{n+1}(x) \text{ with } f_n(x)\to 1 \:\:\forall n\quad\implies\quad \frac{S(x)}{x}\to 1$$

$$x\to\infty \quad\implies\quad S(x)\sim x$$

Comment: Wow this is great thanks, but can you clarify the step that goes from:

$$f_n(x)=\frac{1}{x}\sum_{k=2}^{n} (k-1)\left(x^{1/(k-1)}-x^{1/k}\right) $$

to

$$f_n(x)=1+\sum_{k=2}^{n-1} x^{-(k-1)/k}-(n-1) x^{-(n-1)/n}$$

Before and after that I follow

Comment: $$xf_n(x)=x+2x^{1/2}+3x^{1/3}+...+(n-1)x^{1/(n-1)}-x^{1/2}-2x^{1/3}-...-(n-2)x^{1/(n-1)}-(n-1)x^{1/n}$$ simplify and divide by $x$.